# Is ASP.NET AJAX's 'One request at a time' limitation limited to the use of UpdatePanels?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

We just recently wrote an online job application that is made up of multiple, dynamic modules and each one has individual Create/Edit/Update modes that they invoke asynchronously to avoid full page postbacks.  Basically you save the data in the different modules as you fill out the application and then you submit it at the end.

Being new to AJAX, we initially implemented the modules using UpdatePanels.  Now that we have been using it for awhile we are better understanding some of the limitiations to the UpdatePanel approach.  At any one time the application page has between 30-40 update panels.

So we are getting ready to update the code to be more client focused and use web service calls to get data, with the intent to decrease postbacks as much as possible.  One of the issues that we are running into now is the fact that only one asynchronous request can be running at one time, so if a user answers one question and then answers another while the first one is still saving, the request for the first one is dropped and doesn't complete.

My question is whether this is just a behavior of UpdatePanels and that it will not be an issue when I move to making web service calls from javascript code.  I'm assuming the page can make as many different asynchronous javascript calls at one time as it wants, but I wanted to make sure this was the case as that is a big point we are trying to resolve with a re-write.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is only a limitation of the UpdatePanel.  Its single-request limitation is necessary because the UpdatePanel's asynchronous postbacks are still just postbacks, with all the ViewState roundtripping that is normally associated with full postbacks.  If more than one were allowed to execute simultaneously, the ViewState would quickly get out of sync between them and things would go downhill from there.

Using web services, you can perform as many simultaneous requests as the user's browser supports per-domain.